# How to pass the values in ListView?

Tags: android, string, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to pass the string values in ListView.Firstly I stored all the values in Bundle,which enter through the user then I tried to put all those values in String[] Array.It does show me a error but it doesn't load on the emulator.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);
    Intent myIntent = getIntent(); 
    Bundle b = myIntent.getExtras(); 
    String std = b.getString("std"); 
    String name = b.getString("name");
    String lastname = b.getString("lastname ");
    String country = b.getString("country ");
    String adrs = b.getString("adrs ");
    String pro = b.getString("pro");
    String pcode = b.getString("pcode");

    String[] listItems = new String[7];
    listItems[0] = std ;
    listItems[1] = name;
    listItems[2] = lastname;
    listItems[3] = country;
    listItems[4] = adrs;
    listItems[5] = pro;
    listItems[6] = pcode;

    ArrayAdapter<String> listItemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this
            ,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
            ,listItems);
    ListView lv = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.list_view_id);
    lv.setAdapter(listItemAdapter);

}
```

When i wrote all the hardcode values in String[] Array.It show me whole list.Please help me.Am i miss something.How to fix it??I check all the simmilar Question but It wasn't work.I am very new in Android so please help me.

Comment: You should add the log of the error you obtain.

Comment: Have you tried logging the string values before you put them into the list?

Comment: yeah,I tried to logging the string values.

Comment: yehhh... I fix this problem,Now It works on button when i put on menuitem it dosen't work......:(

Comment: Sounds like this is a problem with how you are passing data, not with your listview.

Comment: check that does bundle provides value or not?? also check the id of list-view is correct

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some Strings are not in the bundle, before using any String from bundle check if it exists with b.containsKey(key)